# Connect from WordPress webpage to a Node.js backend server

Tags: node.js, wordpress

Being new to WordPress, I've been doing some research and yet I don't seem to be able to pinpoint a solution for my need.

In short, I would like to allow a WordPress page to access a Node.js backend, the goal is ultimatly to get access to MongoDB via Node.js, retrieve some data and return a dynamically generated webpage to the website.

I was checking WordPress Rest API but all it seems to do is frontend handling of a WordPress website, creating and editing post, etc.

Unless there's a better way of doing it, I was thinking I might just send a get/post request from the WP page (like, with a form's action) and use Express.js to listen to that request, do the whole workflow on Node.js, then maybe use some npm wordpress API (like this [one](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-wordpress)) to create a wordpress client and add a page or post with the DB extracted content.

I would appreciate some guidance, if any, as to how could one connect from WordPress to a Node.js backend.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it.

If you only need Node for a particular page then you can use your web server (NGINX/Apache) to reverse proxy a particular path to the Node server.

If you had to you could always use an HTML iframe as well but for some reason I feel like that's bad advise.

The method you described would work too. I was considering using GET/POST requests with Express running on a different port for a project I'm working on that uses Wordpress. I decided to go with the solution linked below.

This is probably the method you're looking for based on your description. Skip to solution three if you have to use Wordpress.

[Node JS Reverse Proxy (with Apache)](http://blog.wathmal.me/run-apache-with-node-js-reverse-proxy/)

You can find how to do it with NGINX with a quick search.